# spring cloud - get server name for feign client from application properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I have two microservices `demo-cartservice` and `demo-feignclient` where the `demo-feignclient` fetches resources from `demo-cartservice`

In both projects I set `server.servlet.context-path=/demo/api/` in `application.properties`

The Feign client proxy uses the hardcoded server name for `demo-cartservice`

```
@FeignClient("demo-cartservice/demo/api")
@RibbonClient("demo-cartservice/demo/api")
public interface DemoCartServiceProxy 
{
    @GetMapping("/carts/{cartId}")
    public Cart getCart(@PathVariable("cartId") long id);
}
```

This works fine.

Is there a way to read the server alias from `application.properties` as well, like so:

```
@FeignClient("${cartservice-alias}/${servlet-context}")
@RibbonClient("${cartservice-alias}/${servlet-context}")
public interface DemoCartServiceProxy 
{
    @GetMapping("/carts/{cartId}")
    public Cart getCart(@PathVariable("cartId") long id);
}
```

In `application.properties` of the `demo-feignclient` project I would like to have

```
server.servlet.context-path=/demo/api/
cartservice-alias=demo-cartservice
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry should have checked the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) first. After setting

```
feign.name=demo-cartservice/demo/api
```

in `application.properties` of `demo-feignclient` this works:

```
@FeignClient(name="${feign.name}")
@RibbonClient(name="${feign.name}")
public interface DemoCartServiceProxy 
{
    @GetMapping("/carts/{cartId}")
    public Cart getCart(@PathVariable("cartId") long id);
}
```